# Why is my answer wrong for rotating region in $y=0, x=9, x=0,$ and $x=y^3-2y^2$ about $x$-axis to find volume (shells)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The problem I am working on is to find the volume generated by rotating the region bounded by $y=0, x=9, x=0,$ and $x=y^3-2y^2$ about the $x$-axis. Seeing that $y^3-2y^2<0$ for $y \in (0,2)$, I see that this part of the curve is not in the region, and also that because $y$ greater than $3$ exceeds $9$, I have used the shell method to set up the integral for this problem as $\int_0^2 2 \pi\cdot9ydy + \int_2^32 \pi (9-(y^3-2y^2))ydy$ (in the last integral, I am seeing that the height of the shell is given by the difference between $x=9$ and $x=y^3-2y^2$). Evaluating this integral yields an incorrect answer, $308\pi\over5$ (the correct answer is $113\pi \over5$). What did I do wrong and would be the idea behind the correct answer?

For context, this is problem 137 at [this part of the openstax textbook](https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-2/pages/2-3-volumes-of-revolution-cylindrical-shells), and the answer is linked with the problem.

Comment: There appears to be an error in the given answer:  the volume of the cylinder alone (of height 9 and radius 2 -- your first integral) is larger than that...

Comment: @boojum do my integrals look correct for modelling the problem?

Comment: They look correct to me and my own evaluation produces a volume much larger than the given answer (it may be an answer to a problem that was revised or replaced in the current edition -- where does the problem come from?).  Presumably your first integral "runs" from 0 to 2...

Comment: @boojum I have edited the post to link the problem

Comment: Oy, openstax...  Check your result with some other people as well:  if they also agree with you and not with the text, you may want to alert the author(s) or the site.  What was the volume you found?  (Your calculation is something you should generally include in your posts.)

Comment: @boojum $308\pi\over5$

Comment: Well, that's what I found also.  Too bad the "book" only shows final answers and not the integral set-up that was used...